# UEFI cant get the db list

Tags: uefi

All of a sudden I can't boot up the system any more. I get the message:

[image: screenshot]

How do I proceed from here? Is this a hardware defect? Thanks.

Comment: Can you boot an older kernel ? It is likely a kernel bug see https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1743908 . There are similar bug reports on LP and with RHEL as well. Example https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1719191

Comment: It seems there are a variety of problems causing this error see https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2380700 and https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=251998 , same error message but very different solutions.

Comment: Thanks. I was able to boot from a Manjaro USB stick. But I cant access my data since the home folder was encrypted. But I actually want my system back, not only the data. I cant reinstall all programs again and again each time a kernel or something else gets updated. And I cant change GRUB-files (what ever that is) - I am a user, not a system administrator. Is there no solution to just roll back to the old kernel (what ever that is) and prohibit updating that thing?

Comment: Yes, just boot an old kernel

Comment: Thanks. lol. So you tell the brick layer: just take the gearbox apart and change the oil sensor ... :D

Comment: LOL , yea this site is a bit question / answer. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/82140/how-can-i-boot-with-an-older-kernel-version and you can remove the broken kernel and put the kernel on hold. https://askubuntu.com/questions/18654/how-to-prevent-updating-of-a-specific-package